# Discrete Time to Frequency Response

Tags: discrete-signals, homework, frequency-response

I'm learning (trying to learn) how to find a frequency response. I have a discrete time equation and want to understand the process for finding a frequency response.

Ex:

$$f(n) = 2\,\delta(n)-5\,\delta(n-1) $$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't get a response, this video was helpful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj-Wf2Rpn2A

Comment: You only posted your question a couple of hours ago - you need to allow 24 hours or so for all the DSP leviathans to rouse themselves in all the different corners of the world and focus their vast intellects on your problem.

Comment: @PaulR, yeah, but some of use **won't** deal with this at all.  the OP should attend the *Signals and Systems* or *Linear Systems Theory* or whatever class.  or talk to the professor.  or the graduate teaching assistant.